# Convert String to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, datetime-format

I am storing the dates in a SQLite database in this format:

```
d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa
```

When I retrieve the date with that format I am get every thing fine
except the hour.  The hour is always `00`. Here is my output:

```
String date--->29-Apr-2010,13:00:14 PM
After convrting Date--->1272479414000--Thu Apr 29 00:00:14 GMT+05:30 2010
```

Here is the code:

```
    Date lScheduledDate = CalendarObj.getTime();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa");
    SomeClassObj.setTime(formatter.format(lScheduledDate));

    String lNextDate = SomeClassObj.getTime();
    DateFormat lFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa");
    Date lNextDate = (Date)lFormatter.parse(lNextDate);
    System.out.println("output here"+lNextDate);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay buddies Problem solved, problem with the AM/PM "letter aaa" in format, as I am using 'HH', 'aaa' should not be used, if you use 'aaa' then specify 'hh'

Comment: While in 2010, `java.util.Date` was the class we all used (toghether with `DateFormat` and `Calendar`), for anyone popping by in 2017 or later, those classes are now long outdated. Today one would use the classes in the `java.time` package, for example `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`. There are numerous answers on Stack Overflow to show you how. Go search.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I think your date format does not make sense. There is no 13:00 PM. Remove the "aaa" at the end of your format or turn the HH into hh.

Nevertheless, this works fine for me:

```
String testDate = "29-Apr-2010,13:00:14 PM";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa");
Date date = formatter.parse(testDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

It prints "Thu Apr 29 13:00:14 CEST 2010".

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you may want to use something like SimpleDateFormat.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

You declare your date format and then call the parse method with your string.

```
private static final DateFormat DF = new SimpleDateFormat(...);
Date myDate = DF.parse("1234");
```

And as Guillaume says, set the timezone!

Comment: Not related but DateFormat objects are not thread safe, they should not be declared static because it makes it more likely that they will be accessed from different threads at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a TimeZone in your DateFormat, otherwise it will use the default one (depending on the settings of the computer).

Comment: I specified the timezone in the format as letter z, problem still persists

Comment: Your date string doesn't have time zone info so the z letter won't help, use setTimeZone(...) on the SimpleDateFormat object instead

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

While in 2010, `java.util.Date` was the class we all used (toghether with `DateFormat` and `Calendar`), those classes were always poorly designed and are now long outdated. Today one would use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss");

        String dateTimeStringFromSqlite = "29-Apr-2010,13:00:14";
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStringFromSqlite, formatter);
        System.out.println("output here: " + dateTime);
```

Output is:

> output here: 2010-04-29T13:00:14

### What went wrong in your code?

The combination of uppercase `HH` and `aaa` in your format pattern strings does not make much sense since `HH` is for hour of day, rendering the AM/PM marker from `aaa` superfluous. It should not do any harm, though, and I have been unable to reproduce the exact results you reported. In any case, your comment is to the point no matter if one uses the old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat` or the modern `DateTimeFormatter`:

> 'aaa' should not be used, if you use 'aaa' then specify 'hh'

Lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM, from 01 through 12, so would require an AM/PM marker.

**Other tips**

- In your database, since I understand that SQLite hasn’t got a built-in datetime type, use the standard ISO 8601 format and store time in UTC, for example `2010-04-29T07:30:14Z` (the modern `Instant` class parses and formats such strings as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter).
- Don’t use an offset such as `GMT+05:30` for time zone. Prefer a real time zone, for example Asia/Colombo, Asia/Kolkata or America/New_York.
- If you wanted to use the outdated `DateFormat`, its `parse` method returns a `Date`, so you don’t need the cast in `Date lNextDate = (Date)lFormatter.parse(lNextDate);`.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)