# I am getting date as String from jsp page how to convert it in to java.util.Date

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting date as "`04/26/2013`" and time as "`05:30 AM` "and time zone as"`-12.0`" from the jsp page and getting it in a servlet how can I convert this String values in to `java.util.Date` format . I have tried to append the Strings and got `(04/26/2013 05:30 AM -12.0)` but am not able to use `Dateformat` or `timestamp`

Can anyone suggest a way to solve this ?

Comment: I think you haven't done your search, look here :

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735023/convert-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: this is the String value **04/26/2013 05:30 AM GMT-12.0** but it is showing the error **unparseable date**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes from the time zone format.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy hh:mm a Z");
String t = "04/26/2013 05:30 AM -1200";
String tt = "04/26/2013 05:30 AM GMT -1200";
Date d= df.parse(t);
Date d= df.parse(tt);
```

works for me.

You can read more about time zone format [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)