# How to Convert Date time in "2018-08-07T19:37:24+05:30" pattern Android?

Tags: android, datetime, datetime-format

i want to convert date time in "2018-08-07T19:37:24+05:30" this pattern is it possible in android.?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735023/convert-string-to-java-util-date (except that question is not specifically android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", Locale.getDefault());
dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

See more patterns [here on y-gagar1n's GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/y-gagar1n/8469484)