# Comparing dates in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to compare dates in pipeline. And this is hilarious, the following code works ok in Groovy script console in Jenkins but not in a pipeline:

```
def created = new Date().parse("yyyyMMdd", "20191012")
def now = new Date().minus(30)
println created
println now
if (now > created) {
  println "blah"
} else {
  println "foo"
}
```

In the pipeline this gives me the following output:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [yyyyMMdd, 20191017]
Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), parse(java.lang.String), parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.TimeZone), wait(), clone(), any()
```

I tried to change **new Date().parse** to **Date.parse** but then it exists with:

`org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such static method found: staticMethod java.util.Date parse java.lang.String java.lang.String`

How am I supposed to compare dates then?

**EDIT: Rework using LocalDate**

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def due = 15
def creation_date = "20191012"
def dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
def now = LocalDate.now().format(dateFormat);
def creation = LocalDate.parse(creation_date,  dateFormat)

if (LocalDate.parse(now, dateFormat).minusDays(due) > creation) { 
  println "blah"
} else { 
  println "foo"
}
```

Works at Groovy console, does not work in pipeline, throws an error:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.withscript.WithScriptScript.script
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript@55030b9c
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@23e9719e
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@165471ce
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@124c8a1d
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@124c8a1d
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
```

I'm now totally puzzled how to deal with it...

**EDIT2: SOLUTION**

It appears that the code was pasted into pipeline without 'def' determiners. By trial and error I narrowed down that it was required to have at least **def dateFormat** other vars were not required to have that. Looks like all serializable variables need to be defined via 'def'.

I'm leaving that as it is so maybe sb will benefit from it.

Comment: After changing to one argument with date string, I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. As I mentioned the code in question works with 2 parameters when ran from Jenkins groovy console, but fails to run from within Jenkins pipeline. I'd rather avoid importing a lot of java classess into my pipeline script.

Comment: I think you should read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2735198/1573395

Comment: Thanks, I modified code to fit that model, but still no luck in Jenkins pipeline...